# Limit your use of DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, sqldatareader

I recently saw this, see below. I got `OutofMemoryException` when loading 2.5 million records with `DataTable`. And near the bottom, there is a `table.Dispose()`. Memory usage: 560Mb!  Why use `DataTable` anyway?

```
public string[] GetIDs()
{
   DataTable table = new DataTable();
   using (SqlConnection dwConn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
   {
      dwConn.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = dwConn.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM Customer";
      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      table.Load(reader);
    }
    var result = new string[table.Rows.Count];
    for(int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++ )
    {
       result[i] = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
    }
    table.Dispose();
    table = null;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have got the answer to your own question pretty quickly - why bother asking?

Comment: @geedubb It is to help others who get struck in same kind of situations

Comment: It's not clear what the actual *question* is though...

Comment: I ran into OutOfMemoryException, and this was my solution, not a question.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

I turned this in the following, and the memory used was now 250Mb for 2.5 million records, same as above. The memory used is now less than 45% of the original.

```
public IEnumerable<String> GetIDs()
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    using (var dwConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        dwConn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = dwConn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM Customer";
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
            }
        }                
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Am pretty sure you are doing something wrong with `DataTable`. just `DataTable` is not gonna add `250Mb` of memory

Answer (score 0):

Its good to see that you have a problem to your solution, but i would also recommend to have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419717/ado-net-data-table-vs-data-reader) which depicts that DataReader is a better solution than DataTable, but [it depends on it use as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083193/whats-better-dataset-or-datareader). [After reading this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9104d3e-0736-433c-b403-39a33ac76d2d/datareader-vs-datatable) you will understand memory consumption is expected to be less in case of DataReader.

Another advantage using SqlDataReader is documented in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is:

A part from `Remarks`:

> Changes made to a result set by another process or thread while data
>   is being read may be visible to the user of the SqlDataReader.

So it is a possible reason that you are getting this difference in observation.

Hope it is useful for you and others as well.